# Fix a bump in paver step

Tags: pavers

Our house has a paver patio done by a poor contractor (according to the previous homeowner). The patio is right next to the house foundation. Thanks to the rainy summer, we got a pretty big bump in the paver step which is about 1.5" higher, involving maybe 3-4 pavers. There is another sinking spot (about 2'x2') somewhere else in the patio but only like 1/4" deep, but it does puddle a little when it rains.

I have a feeling that the contractor might not have done the patio base properly (patio was build 2-3 years ago). I wonder if I can simply fix that bump and that sinking spot or should I start over and make sure the base is done right (feels like a pretty big project & not too diy-able since the patio is like 250 sq ft if not more). The patio in general does have 2-3% grading as far as I can tell (with a string level).

If fixing the bump and the sinking spot is all what's needed, could someone give me some advice? I'm somewhat handy but have zero experience in things like this. What I'm planning to do (after doing quite some homework on Google/YouTube/...) is basically:

- pull out the pavers & clean up
- dig 1-2" and add sand
- level & tamp
- put pavers back, glue to cinder blocks
- apply ez-sand

P.s. we may well have some drainage issue in the backyard but we'll have a French drain installed soon (like in a week or two). The downspout and gutter (3") are a bit old but aren't too bad and I do plan to replace with 5" sometime soon

Comment: It will depend what you actually find when you lift the offending paving slabs. But you might as well start by doing that. They can always go down again with less of what's under them, temporarily.

Comment: compact the sand befor laying paver

Comment: you don't have to redo the whole thing, just raise the sunken ones with more sand or pebbles and excavate the proud ones until they are flush. I wouldn't necessarily blame the contractor, but more often than not, seemingly everyone skimps on base material...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis! I remembered the previous owner had some very unpleasant experience with the contractor. And the patio itself doesn't reflect good craftsmanship. I'm guessing fixing the uneven spots with sand/pebbles is perhaps not a permanent solution...? Let's say if the contactor indeed messed up the base, would the situation get worse over time? I had the same concern that @Tim had. We will have improved drainage (French drain around house) soon...

Comment: @Ruskes yup, got a tamper and hopefully it's not too tricky

Comment: Thanks @Tim! That's what I worried about as well. Was hoping it'll stabilize a bit once we fixed the drainage (perhaps the gutter too). Honestly I'm a bit confused by what caused the bump in the first place. The patio in general has a little slope. The downspout is pretty far (5-6' away at least). Earlier this year the bump was barely noticeable, but later this year the situation escalated fast.

Comment: usually you get less settling over time; most of the happy place finding for the bricks happens in the first few years. you might also have roots pushing on it that can't be fixed even with a redo, so it doesn't pay off to be aggressive here, imho. even if a patch only gets you a couple years, that sounds worth it..

Comment: Good point @dandavis thank you very much! We do have a fairly big tree but is like 10' away from the edge of the paver patio. Can tree roots reach that far?

Comment: roots can reach further than the branches.